# can't drag the modal popup

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I created Ajax modal pop up. This is not support drag.

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender" runat="server"
                        TargetControlID="Button1"
                        PopupControlID="Panel1"
                        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
                        CancelControlID="btnCancel"
                        RepositionMode="None"
                        PopupDragHandleControlID="PopUpHeader" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="First Modal Popup" /> 
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="180px" Width="400px" CssClass="ModalWindow">
    <div id="PopUpHeader" style="background-color:Yellow;">
            Error Message
    </div>
    <div>
        My name is error of proble. For comming is satun.
        <br /><br /><br /><br />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btnCancel" runat="server" value="Close" style="float:right;margin-right:20px;" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

How I get the drag and drop.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx

And you must edit `PopupDragHandleControlID="PopUpHeader"` with `PopupDragHandleControlID="Panel1"`

```
PopupDragHandleControlID
```

is controling whict panel are you using with Modal Popup.

Comment: It is not work. PopupDragHandlecontrolID is gets or sets the ID of the element to display as the drag handle for the modal popup.